# Compile Java class with missing code parts

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm looking for some ideas on how to compile Java code with some other pieces of code missing (method calls). I am fully aware that javac will not allow you to compile Java files if cannot find all dependencies. But maybe there is some way how to bypass it, something like force compile.
My bytecode knowledge is not so good but I think some method invoke is just full package definition of class and method name with parameters. So if compiler just puts this data to class file and assume in running process dependency will be available (if not simple NoSuchMethodExp).

Only workaround so far I found is to create empty missing class files with empty methods to "cheat" compiler. Works perfectly but there should be easier way :)
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are already implementing the only reasonable solution :)

Comment: I read your answers and must specify my question more. I am modifying jar file which i dont have sources. I decompile class which i want, make changes, compile to single class and put back to jar and start modified. But to compile i need other jar classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're modifying a jar, you can extract the class files you are not modifying to another directory and include that in the classpath. That way they will be available to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Use Interfaces.

Create the interfaces that have the methods you need. At runtime, inject (Spring, Guice, etc.)  or generate (cglib ...) classes that implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Bad luck! Probably all you can do is to create mock objects for missing parts of code just to compile your code (empty methods, so the compiler can find it).
Another question - if you miss some classes, how will you execute that code?

**UPDATED** according to information provided:

Well, there is another option to modify classes in jar, you can use AOP, and to make it done read about [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) - actually for me this is the easiest option (typically you need to spend time mocking objects, writing empty methods, so I would contribute that time to study new technology, which will help you many times ;)
And btw the easiest way to implement it, if you use Eclipse, is:

1. install [AJDT](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/)
2. create aspect project
3. create aspect which modifies code (depending on what you need to change)
4. add jar file you want to modify
5. immediately get modified code in
   another already packed jar file

Sounds magically :)
In this case you don't need any dependencies in classpath, except for libraries which are needed for new code you add!

Answer (score 0):

Methods aren't dependencies. They are part of the class definition. The only places the java runtime looks for method definitions is in the class def that was compiled at compile time and in its parent classes. If you're problem is that a super class is incomplete, I don't think I can help you.

If not, you could define some of these methods as abstract and than have a child class implement them.

Comment: that thing i trying avoid - implementing empty definitions to satisfy compiler. Is during compile something added special from other classes so they are needed and simple method call is not enough?

Comment: @JIV: No, the only place the compiler looks for method definitions is in the class itself. You might want to give us more detail so we can understand you're problem better. An outline of the code would be helpful.

Comment: @JIV During compilation no thing from other classes can be put to compiled classes. Code inlining can be performed during code execution as part of code optimization by JVM, but not during compiling

Answer (score 0):

What kind of code is missing? Normally this happens if you refer to libraries your compiler can't find. Maybe you simply need to extend the classpath the compiler is searching for classes.

If you really refer to code that is not available yet you need to implement at least those methods you refer to. But that sounds strange... maybe you can clear things up.