# Possible to decompile Java program

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiling

I have a Java program someone else wrote and I'd like to "decompile it" into its sources so I can modify its code. I have tried to do it and have decompiled a jar but when I try to recompile the Java files into jar's I get a bunch of dependency issues because I do not have the source files for the dependencies(although I have some of them but it doesn't seem to help).

Is there any program where I can drag and drop the Java exe or install directory and it will, I guess, decompile everything so I can modify some of its sources and recompile it? I've done this before but can't recall what app I used. The original program is written in eclipse.

Comment: If you are using windows then this is a very good JAVA decompiler http://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: @vikiiii: Yes, I've used it to get at the source code I want to change.That is not the issue. It is trying to get the source code to compile because of all the dependencies spread out everywhere.

Comment: To compile it and add jar-files to the classpath take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946071/re-compile-a-java-class-from-jar)
If you have not already you could try the decompiler [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr)

Comment: Is the original application open source? If yes, then see where you can find the original source code. Otherwise, make sure that what you're doing is allowed according to the license of the software that you're modifying.

Comment: i asked same thing long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661951/compile-java-class-with-missing-code-parts

Comment: @JIV I'm not even sure why java needs the missing dependencies to compile. I would think it would have no problem filling in the dependencies after the fact. (obviously there is type checking and such that will be missing but it would be nice if one could bypass that)

Answer (score 2):

The code you are attempting to re-compile has dependencies on classes you don't have.

Rather than re-compiling the whole jar, you only need to re-compile the classes you changed.

If these classes depend on classes you don't have you can create stubs for those classes which will allow you to compile the classes you changed.

Comment: There are a ton. Dependencies on dependencies... using stuff from eclipse(ui stuff), many subdirectories of things spread out. It would be difficult to do it all by hand. If I could just tell javac to search the directory and **all** subdirectories for jars and class files then it should easily find them and compile. (I have gotten some of the java files to compile but other still need more dependencies fixed)

Comment: You can add `directory-with-jars/*` to the class path. This is preferable if you have the jars somewhere.  Otehrwise, if you use your IDE to create the stubs, it doesn't take long.

Comment: The jars I need to add are all in many different subdirectories. I'm having to add a huge number of paths to get it to work. I'm slowly getting the dependencies down BUT the command line is becoming huge and unwieldy. It would be better to have some way to automate this. I'm doing it from the cmd line and it's very annoying. I wish I could just drop the root directory to use as a base and have something build the dependency list for me and compile the file.

Comment: You can find when all and copy them to one directory in explorer (or with find under UNIX). I find using the command line very avoid too, which is why I use an IDE. ;) I am surprised your code really needs so many jars to compile, anything over 10 is excessive IMHO.

Comment: Are you able to run the original program? Then for compiling, use the same classpath as for running.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. There were also some errors from JD-gui where it redefined variables for no apparent reason and after taking care of them there were far less dependencies needed than I thought. Everything seems to work now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The program has about 150 jars. Not my doing. About half are in one directory and the rest are spread out in varies subdirectories. Because JD didn't decompile perfectly I was assuming most of the errors were due to dependency issues when they were not. (In any case it would still be nice to automate the process. (essentially form a java project from a java app))

Comment: I use an IDE which uses maven. maven keeps track of all the dependencies, downloading them as required. I don't need to keep track of where any of the jar actually are or if I have the right version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to used jd-gui.exe. It can easy to decompile the jar file and content will see clearly ...